# How to use Sly Scroller jQuery item based navigation?

Tags: jquery, sly-scroller

I am trying to make use of [Sly Scroller](http://darsa.in/sly/) for horizontal scrolling. I have tried to read and understand the documentation but I just don't understand how to make use of it.

Can anyone help me getting started maybe with simpler examples compared to reading the documentation, or even specify any `jsfiddle` implementation or a tutorial on the subject?

Answer (score 2):

Before i give you an example i wanted you to precise your environment (are you using php framework for example ?)
First of all you to make sure that you have charged these scripts : 
1-[jquery 1.7] or > 2-[sly.min.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/darsain/sly/master/dist/sly.min.js) 3-[modernizr.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.js)

.
Tips : you can use bower for that 
next you have to add this script

```
<script type="text/javascript">


            jQuery(function($) {
                  'use strict';

                  // -------------------------------------------------------------
                  //   Basic Navigation
                  // -------------------------------------------------------------
                  (function() {
                    var $frame = $('#basic');
                    var $slidee = $frame.children('ul').eq(0);
                    var $wrap = $frame.parent();

                    // Call Sly on frame
                    $frame.sly({
                      horizontal: 1,
                      itemNav: 'basic',
                      smart: 1,
                      activateOn: 'click',
                      mouseDragging: 1,
                      touchDragging: 1,
                      releaseSwing: 1,
                      startAt: 3,
                      scrollBar: $wrap.find('.scrollbar'),
                      scrollBy: 1,
                      pagesBar: $wrap.find('.pages'),
                      activatePageOn: 'click',
                      speed: 300,
                      elasticBounds: 1,
                      easing: 'easeOutExpo',
                      dragHandle: 1,
                      dynamicHandle: 1,
                      clickBar: 1,

                      // Buttons
                      forward: $wrap.find('.forward'),
                      backward: $wrap.find('.backward'),
                      prev: $wrap.find('.prev'),
                      next: $wrap.find('.next'),
                      prevPage: $wrap.find('.prevPage'),
                      nextPage: $wrap.find('.nextPage')
                    });

                    // To Start button
                    $wrap.find('.toStart').on('click', function() {
                      var item = $(this).data('item');
                      // Animate a particular item to the start of the frame.
                      // If no item is provided, the whole content will be animated.
                      $frame.sly('toStart', item);
                    });

                    // To Center button
                    $wrap.find('.toCenter').on('click', function() {
                      var item = $(this).data('item');
                      // Animate a particular item to the center of the frame.
                      // If no item is provided, the whole content will be animated.
                      $frame.sly('toCenter', item);
                    });

                    // To End button
                    $wrap.find('.toEnd').on('click', function() {
                      var item = $(this).data('item');
                      // Animate a particular item to the end of the frame.
                      // If no item is provided, the whole content will be animated.
                      $frame.sly('toEnd', item);
                    });

                    // Add item
                    $wrap.find('.add').on('click', function() {
                      $frame.sly('add', '<li>' + $slidee.children().length + '</li>');
                    });

                    // Remove item
                    $wrap.find('.remove').on('click', function() {
                      $frame.sly('remove', -1);
                    });
                  }());

                  // -------------------------------------------------------------
                  //   Centered Navigation
                  // -------------------------------------------------------------
                  (function() {
                    var $frame = $('#centered');
                    var $wrap = $frame.parent();

                    // Call Sly on frame
                    $frame.sly({
                      horizontal: 1,
                      itemNav: 'centered',
                      smart: 1,
                      activateOn: 'click',
                      mouseDragging: 1,
                      touchDragging: 1,
                      releaseSwing: 1,
                      startAt: 4,
                      scrollBar: $wrap.find('.scrollbar'),
                      scrollBy: 1,
                      speed: 300,
                      elasticBounds: 1,
                      easing: 'easeOutExpo',
                      dragHandle: 1,
                      dynamicHandle: 1,
                      clickBar: 1,

                      // Buttons
                      prev: $wrap.find('.prev'),
                      next: $wrap.find('.next')
                    });
                  }());

                  // -------------------------------------------------------------
                  //   Force Centered Navigation
                  // -------------------------------------------------------------
                  (function() {
                    var $frame = $('#forcecentered');
                    var $wrap = $frame.parent();

                    // Call Sly on frame
                    $frame.sly({
                      horizontal: 1,
                      itemNav: 'forceCentered',
                      smart: 1,
                      activateMiddle: 1,
                      activateOn: 'click',
                      mouseDragging: 1,
                      touchDragging: 1,
                      releaseSwing: 1,
                      startAt: 0,
                      scrollBar: $wrap.find('.scrollbar'),
                      scrollBy: 1,
                      speed: 300,
                      elasticBounds: 1,
                      easing: 'easeOutExpo',
                      dragHandle: 1,
                      dynamicHandle: 1,
                      clickBar: 1,

                      // Buttons
                      prev: $wrap.find('.prev'),
                      next: $wrap.find('.next')
                    });
                  }());

                  // -------------------------------------------------------------
                  //   Cycle By Items
                  // -------------------------------------------------------------
                  (function() {
                    var $frame = $('#cycleitems');
                    var $wrap = $frame.parent();

                    // Call Sly on frame
                    $frame.sly({
                      horizontal: 1,
                      itemNav: 'basic',
                      smart: 1,
                      activateOn: 'click',
                      mouseDragging: 1,
                      touchDragging: 1,
                      releaseSwing: 1,
                      startAt: 0,
                      scrollBar: $wrap.find('.scrollbar'),
                      scrollBy: 1,
                      speed: 300,
                      elasticBounds: 1,
                      easing: 'easeOutExpo',
                      dragHandle: 1,
                      dynamicHandle: 1,
                      clickBar: 1,

                      // Cycling
                      cycleBy: 'items',
                      cycleInterval: 1000,
                      pauseOnHover: 1,

                      // Buttons
                      prev: $wrap.find('.prev'),
                      next: $wrap.find('.next')
                    });

                    // Pause button
                    $wrap.find('.pause').on('click', function() {
                      $frame.sly('pause');
                    });

                    // Resume button
                    $wrap.find('.resume').on('click', function() {
                      $frame.sly('resume');
                    });

                    // Toggle button
                    $wrap.find('.toggle').on('click', function() {
                      $frame.sly('toggle');
                    });
                  }());

                  // -------------------------------------------------------------
                  //   Cycle By Pages
                  // -------------------------------------------------------------
                  (function() {
                    var $frame = $('#cyclepages');
                    var $wrap = $frame.parent();

                    // Call Sly on frame
                    $frame.sly({
                      horizontal: 1,
                      itemNav: 'basic',
                      smart: 1,
                      activateOn: 'click',
                      mouseDragging: 1,
                      touchDragging: 1,
                      releaseSwing: 1,
                      startAt: 0,
                      scrollBar: $wrap.find('.scrollbar'),
                      scrollBy: 1,
                      pagesBar: $wrap.find('.pages'),
                      activatePageOn: 'click',
                      speed: 300,
                      elasticBounds: 1,
                      easing: 'easeOutExpo',
                      dragHandle: 1,
                      dynamicHandle: 1,
                      clickBar: 1,

                      // Cycling
                      cycleBy: 'pages',
                      cycleInterval: 1000,
                      pauseOnHover: 1,
                      startPaused: 1,

                      // Buttons
                      prevPage: $wrap.find('.prevPage'),
                      nextPage: $wrap.find('.nextPage')
                    });

                    // Pause button
                    $wrap.find('.pause').on('click', function() {
                      $frame.sly('pause');
                    });

                    // Resume button
                    $wrap.find('.resume').on('click', function() {
                      $frame.sly('resume');
                    });

                    // Toggle button
                    $wrap.find('.toggle').on('click', function() {
                      $frame.sly('toggle');
                    });
                  }());

                  // -------------------------------------------------------------
                  //   One Item Per Frame
                  // -------------------------------------------------------------
                  (function() {
                    var $frame = $('#oneperframe');
                    var $wrap = $frame.parent();

                    // Call Sly on frame
                    $frame.sly({
                      horizontal: 1,
                      itemNav: 'forceCentered',
                      smart: 1,
                      activateMiddle: 1,
                      mouseDragging: 1,
                      touchDragging: 1,
                      releaseSwing: 1,
                      startAt: 0,
                      scrollBar: $wrap.find('.scrollbar'),
                      scrollBy: 1,
                      speed: 300,
                      elasticBounds: 1,
                      easing: 'easeOutExpo',
                      dragHandle: 1,
                      dynamicHandle: 1,
                      clickBar: 1,

                      // Buttons
                      prev: $wrap.find('.prev'),
                      next: $wrap.find('.next')
                    });
                  }());

                  // -------------------------------------------------------------
                  //   Crazy
                  // -------------------------------------------------------------
                  (function() {
                    var $frame = $('#crazy');
                    var $slidee = $frame.children('ul').eq(0);
                    var $wrap = $frame.parent();

                    // Call Sly on frame
                    $frame.sly({
                      horizontal: 1,
                      itemNav: 'basic',
                      smart: 1,
                      activateOn: 'click',
                      mouseDragging: 1,
                      touchDragging: 1,
                      releaseSwing: 1,
                      startAt: 3,
                      scrollBar: $wrap.find('.scrollbar'),
                      scrollBy: 1,
                      pagesBar: $wrap.find('.pages'),
                      activatePageOn: 'click',
                      speed: 300,
                      elasticBounds: 1,
                      easing: 'easeOutExpo',
                      dragHandle: 1,
                      dynamicHandle: 1,
                      clickBar: 1,

                      // Buttons
                      forward: $wrap.find('.forward'),
                      backward: $wrap.find('.backward'),
                      prev: $wrap.find('.prev'),
                      next: $wrap.find('.next'),
                      prevPage: $wrap.find('.prevPage'),
                      nextPage: $wrap.find('.nextPage')
                    });

                    // To Start button
                    $wrap.find('.toStart').on('click', function() {
                      var item = $(this).data('item');
                      // Animate a particular item to the start of the frame.
                      // If no item is provided, the whole content will be animated.
                      $frame.sly('toStart', item);
                    });

                    // To Center button
                    $wrap.find('.toCenter').on('click', function() {
                      var item = $(this).data('item');
                      // Animate a particular item to the center of the frame.
                      // If no item is provided, the whole content will be animated.
                      $frame.sly('toCenter', item);
                    });

                    // To End button
                    $wrap.find('.toEnd').on('click', function() {
                      var item = $(this).data('item');
                      // Animate a particular item to the end of the frame.
                      // If no item is provided, the whole content will be animated.
                      $frame.sly('toEnd', item);
                    });

                    // Add item
                    $wrap.find('.add').on('click', function() {
                      $frame.sly('add', '<li>' + $slidee.children().length + '</li>');
                    });

                    // Remove item
                    $wrap.find('.remove').on('click', function() {
                      $frame.sly('remove', -1);
                    });
                  }());
                });
    </script>
```

as you can see in the previous script there is several navigations you have to just choose one of them in the html part here

```
    <div class="frame" id="cycleitems">// you have to put in the id the animation that you like
        <ul class="clearfix">

           <!-- please insert inside the li tag what you want to put inside the sly scroller :D -->

           <li> some code here for example <img src ="blabla" /> </li>
           <li> some code here for example <img src ="blabla" /> </li>
           <li> some code here for example <img src ="blabla" /> </li>
        </ul></div>
```

and finally the css part :

```
    .crazy ul li:nth-child(2n) {
      width: 100px;
      margin: 0 4px 0 20px;
    }

    .crazy ul li:nth-child(3n) {
      width: 300px;
      margin: 0 10px 0 5px;
    }

    .crazy ul li:nth-child(4n) {
      width: 400px;
      margin: 0 30px 0 2px;
    }
```

if you have any farther questions don't hesitate to ask :)

Comment: Cool, Thanks. I think you are missing the css for .clearfix/<li> or whatever, see here... https://codepen.io/ddbdavis/pen/LGVgRa for example

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the Previous answer, if you want to callback, you can use

```
$frame.sly('on','active',function(e,i){
   console.log("e",e);
   console.log("i",i);
   console.log(this.items[i].el.getAttribute("data-filter"));
});
```

this.items[i].el will get your active li. Note: As I used this, not $('this') I need to use getAttribute(), as it is a DOM object.

I'm also new to Js and Jquery, so it might not be the best soultion, but it works for me